# Displaying informations from database according to an element chosen in the drop down list

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a JSP page where I placed a dropdownlist with different options. How can I display information corresponding to a project from database, once I choose the city in the dropdownlist without loading the page? Do I need JavaScript to do that?

Comment: Please provide more details, some code, what have you already tried? So people here can help you and lead you to the right solution, otherwise your question will be downvoted or maybe closed.

Comment: Yes, of course you need javascript

Comment: I have tried several code yesterday but with no results. Once i finish the code i'm workin on it right now i ll post it. Thank u

Comment: And to answer your question, yes with `Javascript` and the `onchange` event of the dropdown list you can change the displayed information according to the selected value from your dropdown list.